# DAX formula compatibility in DirectQuery PowerBI- Match Value from another table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have two tables where they are connected by Table1[ColA] &Table1[ColB].

Now I am trying to match the values from Table1[ColB] with Table2[ColB] & return the result in Table2[ColC]. Where the result should be -

```
if it matches "Found"
doesn't match "Not-Found"
else Empty
```

The Key is to use Use the `LOOKUPVALUE` function to see, if the value exists.

Now I can use the following query for the output

```
Col_C = 
         Var out1 = LOOKUPVALUE(Table2[ColB],Table2[ColB],Table1[ColB])
         Var out2 = IF(out1 = "", "Not Found","Found")
         Var out3 = if(Table1[ColB] = "", "Empty", out2)
return out3
```

But when the data is DirectQuery it seems like `LOOKUPVALUE` is not supported.

I found one [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/dax-formula-compatibility-in-directquery-mode-ssas-2016?view=asallproducts-allversions) on Microsoft site saying the DAX formula compatibility in DirectQuery.

Do anyone knows how to query this output or replacement of `LOOKUPVALUE` in DirectQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try `IN VALUES` instead of `LOOKUPVALUE = ""`:

```
Col_C =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    ISEMPTY ( Table1[ColB] ), "Empty",
    Table1[ColB] IN VALUES ( Table2[ColB] ), "Found",
    "Not Found"
)
```